# Pass string to json with jquery and loop the elements

Tags: php, jquery, json

Hello there I have a really complex php script that produces a javascript file in jquery
There is a string that is stored in an input type text and I want to converted into json.
The input type text has undedined number of elements.
So I initisialize the string in the input box

```
<input type="text" id="selectbuttons" value="{}">
```

After some actions the string in the input box is something like that:

```
{"button":"bt1","style":"style1"},{"button":"bt2","style":"style2"}
```

etc...

Then this is my script , i use the function **addScriptto** to add it to the document's header, also I am using the core of jquery jquery-1.6.2.min.js to make the json object

```
$document->addScriptto('
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var loaded=$("#selectButtons").val();
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(loaded);
}); //end of dom ready

');
```

But I can't make it work, when the string is not empty
Is there something wrong with my json syntax? Also, I would be later able to loop all the elements and retrieve the data? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON string should be in an array format like below

```
[{"button":"bt1","style":"style1"},{"button":"bt2","style":"style2"}]
```

And then you can use the $.each to loop through the JOSN values as below:

```
$.each(yourJSONstring,function(i,values) {
  //yourJSONstring holds the JSON array
  // i is just the loop index. it will increment by 1 in every loop
  alert(values.button) //will alert bt1 in the 1st loop, bt2 in 2nd
  alert(values.style) //will alert style1 in 1st loop, style2 in 2nd
  //You can have values here of the keys in JSON using the dot notation as above and do your operations.
})
```

Comment: This aint working I can't create the json object with parse json

Comment: @Theodore if you have the value already in JSON format like [{'button':'bt1'},{'button':'bt2'}], you don;t need to do parseJSON(loaded), just pass the loaded variable to $.each() and make sure you have the square brackets at the beginning and end of the JSON string, else it will not work and loop through each character instead of each key.

Comment: `var yourJSONstring=[{"button":"bt1","style":"style1"},{"button":"bt2","style":"style2"}];

$.each(yourJSONstring,function(i,values) {
  
  alert(values.button)
  alert(values.style) }`
This piece of code does not work
what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Theodore The closing bracket of $.each() is missing in the code, so it is not working. Just add another closing ')' after the last '}'

Comment: I just noticed it
Works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

maybe just put `[ ... ]` around the JSON so it is understood as an array, something like:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '[' + loaded + ']' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your JSON syntax is wrong. You should have it like:

```
[{"button":"bt1","style":"style1"},{"button":"bt2","style":"style2"}]
```

and then you will have array of your objects.

Comment: Still I am getting an error, this is my string in the input type text  now:

`[{"button":"small","style":"Link"}]`

Also I hacve tried to use the function without the jquery prefix as I am using it in dom ready

`var obj = $.parseJSON(loaded);` but still no luck

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't work? When actually your code is executed? From the code you posted, I can see that your code will be executed when document is ready, and then your textbox is empty. Is that what you want to do or you have some button? Can you give me more details?

Comment: I have some other stuff with Jquery on the some page. When I am trying your code the other stuff breaks
This works fine though

`var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('."'".'[{"name":"John","style":"hello"},{"helo":"world"}]'."'".');`

Note that Iam using string concatanation as I am inside of a php script

Comment: that makes sense, because you need string in order to parse it. what I wrote was just a valid json object example. I'm glad you solved it